# How to efficiently retrieve a list of file names and lengths

Tags: c#, directoryinfo, filesysteminfo

I have a C# application where at one point it scans a folder that could potentially contain 10s of thousands of files. It the filters that list by name and length and selects a relatively small number for processing.

Simplified code:

```
DirectoryInfo directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(path);
FileSystemInfo[] fileSystemInfos = directoryInfo.GetFileSystemInfos();
List<MyInfo> myInfoList = fileSystemInfos
    .Where(f => (f.Attributes & FileAttributes.Directory) != FileAttributes.Directory))
    .Select(f => new MyInfo {
        FilePath = f.FullName,
        FileSize = new FileInfo(f.FullName).Length,
        })
    .ToList();
```

The logic later selects a handful of files and verifies a non-zero length.

The problem is that the individual calls to `FileInfo(f.FullName).Length` are killing performance. Under the covers, I see that FileInfo internally stores a WIN32_FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DATA struct that contains length (fileSizeLow and fileSizeHigh), but does not exposes that as a property.

**Question:** Is there an *simple* alternative to the above that can retrieve file names *and* lengths efficiently without the extra FileInfo.Length call?

My alternative is to make the MyInfo.FileSize property a lazy load property, but I wanted to check for a more direct approach first.

Comment: Instead of calling GetFileSystemInfos can't you just call GetFiles?  GetFiles returns FileInfo objects which have a Length property.  Doing this also means that you don't have to manually weed out the directory entries as only files will be returned.

Comment: That sounds like the answer. I'll give it a try. I expect that will eliminate the is-not-directory check also.

Comment: @ajz Thanks for the answer. Just  experimenting in powershell yielded a several-fold efficiency increase for a local folder. I'll test in C# against a network folder at next opportunity, where I am hoping for a much more dramatic improveent. FYI - The folder being processed normally has at most a handful of unprocessed files, but after a processing outage it was taking forever to clear out the backlog with the existing logic, and we had to resort to spoon feeding files. This fix should allow for a much more speedy recovery. If you post as answer, I will accept.